# How do I access a NAS through my ASP.NET MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, fileserver

I'd like to access a Fileserver (NAS) through my ASP.NET MVC Application and can't find a way to do that in a correct way.

What I've done so far is:

- Created a User with Read/Write permissions on a directory on my NAS
- Created a virtual directory on my IIS Server that is connected to the nas directory with the previously defined usercredentials

Now if I navigate to my virtual directory (AppliCationIPAdress/NAS) I get automaticaly redirected to \NASIPAdress\My\Directory. On the NAS loginnotifications I get the info, that somewone connected to my directory with the given credentials => That is how it should be

But if I access the NAS directory trough my MVC application (no matter if i use the UNC or the virtual directory redirection) i get an access denied erromessage and in the NAS loginnotifications there is not listed my prepared useraccount but my webserver as user who tried to login.

```
        var dirName = Server.MapPath("~/NAS/Dir/");
        ViewBag.Message = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dirName );
```

Could someone please explain why that is happening and what I have to do if i want to access files on a fileservice throuh my mvc application?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the service account rights to access the filearea, or run the app with a user that has rights

Comment: You mean I have to grant accessrights to the networkservice account right? But I can't figure out how to do that because that account cant be found if I try to add it to the users list.

Comment: In the textbox under secutiry for the folder type "network" and then press "check names" the resuling list should have "Network service"

Comment: AH, wait a second.. Your adding the rights on the NAS right? Network service is a local user on the IIS machine

Comment: yes that's my problem but even if I want to gain accessrights to the networkservice on the iis machine I can't select it as user, the search does not find it

Comment: Strange that it does not show up, but it wont help with the Network service account anyway. You need to change the service account to a user that is on the AD and give that rights to the folder on the NAS. You change user under Applications pools, select the pool and click advanced settings

Comment: if i change the user i get a "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable." no matter if it is the recommended "ApplicationPoolIdentity" or a useraccount. btw. the error not finding the networkservice was a language problem because i have a german configuration and there the networkservice is called "Netzwerkdienst" :)

Comment: OP, @Anders, any luck? please post back here if anything useful came out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What worked for was:

1. Have same user account and password in NAS and IIS Server.
2. Create an application pool for your web app or use the default app pool and change the user account to the same mentioned before. Steps:

   - Go To **IIS Manager**
   - Click on **Application Pools**
   - Right click on the app pool assigned to your web app and select **Advanced settings...**
   - In section **Process Model** change the **Identity** field to the user account mentioned above.
   - Click on the **3 dots** button located at the right of the field
   - Select **Custom account** and click on **Set...** button
   - Set **username**, **password** and **password confirmation** (same user account mentioned above.

Hope it helps!

FranciscoG